# Lexmark Z25 on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, lexmark-printer

So I was about to install my printer for Windows 7, go to Lexmark's website and poof.  They say they do not have a driver for Windows 7.  I go to Microsoft's Windows 7 Compatibility Center and it says it installs automatically without extra software:

http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Details.aspx?type=Hardware&p=Lexmark%20Z25%20Inkjet%20Printer&v=Lexmark&uid=15J0070&l=en-US&pf=3&pi=8&c=Printers%20%26%20Scanners&sc=Ink-Jet%20Printers&os=32-bit

Anyone have any idea how I would get this to install?  I plugged in the USB and it failed to install it.

Comment: You might define "failed to install it" more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually no way to install this on Windows 7.  I have installed a VMWare Container with Windows XP which I was able to connect to via USB on a remote computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the installer and go to properties, and enable compatability mode for Windows Vista.

See if that sorts it out?

Comment: There is no installer.  Only an inf file.